# How to create unix socket

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, sockets, haproxy

I am installing HAProxy from source. My example conf file tries to configure a socket

```
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats level admin
```

How can I create such a socket? I'm on CentOS 7.

Comment: AFAIK it's HAProxy who creates the socket. Does your HAProxy fail to do this? What is the exact error message/log/whatever?

Comment: Indeed, this was a permission problem. HAProxy service needs to start as root.